# SoapClient classmap inside a php namespace - soapfault class not found

Tags: php, namespaces

I've generated a set of php classes using **easyWsdl2PHP** and they are working ok, but when I place the generated class inside a namespace like such...

```
namespace myCompany\ourService
```

then initially when calling this code...

```
$params = array("classmap"=>self::$classmap,"trace" => true,"exceptions" => true);     
$this->soapClient = new SoapClient($url,$params);
```

I get this error

> Class 'myCompany\ourService\SoapClient' not found

which I fix by calling `new \SoapClient($url...` (notice the backslash at the start, escapes the namespace), but now basically it is complaining it cant find the 'response' object, that is my Request is placed in a 'SALE' object and passed to the soap call, the error is like so

> Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] Class 'SALEResponse' not found

How can I use php namespaces correctly within my code, how to get Soap in php to use the name spaces correctly? I have two very similar services I need to connect to, both with 'sale' methods, and many other commonly named elements that are not compatible, so placing them inside a php namespace appears to be a good solution, as the code is generated, I could rename each `Sale` to `Service1_Sale` and `Service2_Sale`, but that is far from ideal. Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found a solution :

```
private static $classmap = array('SALE'=>'ourCompany\ourService\SALE'
,'SALEREQUEST_V1'=>'ourCompany\ourService\SALEREQUEST_V1'
,'AUTHORIZATION_V1'=>'ourCompany\ourService\AUTHORIZATION_V1'
,'RECEIPTREQUEST_V1'=>'ourCompany\ourService\RECEIPTREQUEST_V1'
,'SALEResponse'=>'ourCompany\ourService\SALEResponse'
);
```

where i've added the `ourCompany\ourService\` to include the namespace i'm using.